# search filter for Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I'm creating a job search app which shows job infomation as listview where the data is from WAMP server database. I encounter a problem : Cannot resolve method 'getStringArrayList' , when I'm making a search filter for this Listview. Please see line 11 of SearchFilter.java. Could anyone help? thank you very much!

SearchFilter.java

```
public class SearchFilter extends ListActivity {
private EditText filterText = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);
filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        getStringArrayList()));                   ***<<<<< this line !***
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                          int count) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}

};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
filterText.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

}
```

Comment: Did you just ask the same question you asked 3 hours ago *again*?

Comment: Calvin don't ask the same question many times, ask it once and wait  :)

Comment: I'm so sorry. I spend much time on it but still can't make it. I just hope someone can help but no reply. And It seems that there is no way to push the question to the top. Anyway, should I delete this post ?